# Docker Desktop for Windows mount a folder but can't open it after several hours

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I am using the latest stable version of **Docker Desktop for Windows**, I run a container with shared folder by:

```
docker run -itd -v X:/one_folder:/data image_name
```

`X` is a windows drive which was successfully shared in docker desktop for windows setting.

After this, I open a ssh session for the system and can open the mounted folder correctly. But the second day (the container is still running with daemon mode), 
the mounted folder show this:[list result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35p4e.png).

But when I `cd` to the path and run `ls`, I get this error

> reading directory .: Input/output error

How could I solve the problem?

Comment: thanks for the fix of description~

Comment: Did you do anything like shut get on/off VPN, shut down the computer, restart it or restart Docker for Windows? The volume mount may not survive that. If you get into this situation, I recommend either restarting the container or stopping the container, restart Docker for Windows and restarting the container.